# Rx: Wait for first item for a period of time

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I would like to transform my legacy event-based method to observable based, but I am quite new to Rx, so I am stuck now.

I have an event source, which is an observable by now. At a certain point in time, I have to start a method that ends either by returning the next element in the line or null if it is timed out.

The event-based approach looks like this:

```
public async Task<ReaderEvent> WaitForReaderAsync(int PlaceId, TimeSpan waitFor)
{
    ReaderEvent result = null;
    using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(new [] { topLevelToken }))
    {
        cts.CancelAfter(waitFor);

        EventHandler<ReaderEvent> localHandler = (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PlaceId == PlaceId)
            {
                result = e;
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        };

        ReaderEventHandler += localHandler;
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(waitFor, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //...
        }

        ReaderEventHandler -= localHandler;
    }

    return result;
}
```

As you can see, the idea is that the delay is cancelled either by the arrival of the event I am waiting for or the token source is cancelled by configuration after that specific amount of time. Quite clean.

Now, the Rx version:

```
public async Task<ReaderEvent> WaitForReaderAsync(int PlaceId, TimeSpan waitFor)
{
    ReaderEvent result = null;

    var observable = _OnReaderEvent.FirstAsync(r => r.PlaceId == PlaceId);

    using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(new [] { topLevelToken }))
    {
        cts.CancelAfter(waitFor);
        using (observable.Subscribe(x => {
            result = x;
            cts.Cancel();
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(waitFor, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Not so clean... even worse...
I have tried with Timeout extension too. But as this is a one-shot subscribtion, I still need waiting somehow before I dispose the subscription. The only difference would be that the OnError would cancel the local token, not the built-in mechanism of CancelAfter.

Is there any batter / more concise (more relying on Rx) way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just go with a simple Rx version of the code:

```
public async Task<ReaderEvent> WaitForReaderAsync(int PlaceId, TimeSpan waitFor)
{
    return await
        _OnReaderEvent
            .Where(r => r.PlaceId == PlaceId)
            .Buffer(waitFor, 1)
            .Select(xs => xs.FirstOrDefault())
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
            .ToTask();
}
```

Comment: It does not terminate this way. But after adding a .FirstOrDefaultAsync() before .ToTask() made it work. Yes, this is the cleanest of all. And I can add my cancellation token seamlessly. Thank you!

Comment: @ZorgoZ - There's no use doing the cancellation token code as you're not actually cancelling the underlying observable with it. It's a bit pointless.

Answer (score 3):

you could try with:

```
var values = await _OnReaderEvent
  .Where(r => r.PlaceId == placeId)
  .Buffer(waitFor, 1)
  .FirstAsync(); // get list of matching elements during waitFor time

return values.FirstOrDefault(); // return first element or null if the list is empty
```

Comment: Well, it looks like in this case r is IList<ReaderEvent>, but the other way around looked promising:

var values = await _OnReaderEvent.FirstAsync(r => r.PlaceId == PlaceId).Buffer(waitFor);
return values.FirstOrDefault();

Still, Buffer() seems to be blocking. If no event is in the line, it does not terminate :(

Comment: Buffer return List<T>, where T is type of Observable items. It's a list of all items that were produced during time window of waitFor and it should return empty list every waitFor. If you do Buffer -> FirstAsync then you will get first list.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229813(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Ahh.. got the point. Then this is what I need: var values = await _OnReaderEvent.Where(r => r.PlaceId == PlaceId).Buffer(waitFor, 1).FirstAsync(); return values.FirstOrDefault(); You pointed me into the right direction!

Comment: Almost :) You missed the 1 as Buffer parameter, which is important to immediately return as the first element arrives. Unfortunately, none of the methods is accepting cancellation token.

Comment: You can wrap all that with cancellation token and just dispose subscriptions on cancelled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155761/discussion-between-krzysztof-skowronek-and-zorgoz).

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in lots of different ways. Here is one, utilizing the [`Amb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211783(v=vs.103)), `Return`, `Delay` and `FirstAsync` operators:

```
public Task<ReaderEvent> WaitForReaderAsync(int PlaceId, TimeSpan waitFor)
{
    return _OnReaderEvent
        .Where(r => r.PlaceId == PlaceId)
        .Amb(Observable.Return(default(ReaderEvent)).Delay(waitFor))
        .FirstAsync()
        .ToTask();
}
```

In the abnormal case that the `_OnReaderEvent` observable is completed or completes during the waiting, the resulting `Task` will transition to a faulted state, with the exception being `InvalidOperationException` "Sequence contains no elements".

Another implementation, functionaly equivalent to the previous one, using the `Timeout` operator:

```
public Task<ReaderEvent> WaitForReaderAsync(int PlaceId, TimeSpan waitFor)
{
    return _OnReaderEvent
        .Where(r => r.PlaceId == PlaceId)
        .FirstAsync()
        .Timeout(waitFor, Observable.Return(default(ReaderEvent)))
        .ToTask();
}
```